# Installing statsmodels package for exponential smoothing

Tags: python

I have been trying to install statsmodels in jupyter, from the anaconda prompt, to use exponential smoothing and other techniques.
I tried this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git
```

But this is what I get:

```
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    building 'statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalman_loglike' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Any suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing Visual C++?

Comment: I thought Conda helped with some of the C++ and Fortran dependencies. I'm not sure if that would help you with your visual C++ problem. Obviously installing VS C++ build tools should solve it for you, but if you dont want to install it, then you could try using conda to install Numpy, Scipy, and then Statsmodel.

Comment: Hi, I already installed Numpy and Scipy using conda. And I also have Visual Studio Code

Comment: @mkrieger1 so I installed Visual Studio Code like a month ago. Then I followed a link to download Visual C++ but saw that it was the same thing.

Comment: Even after installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.1 it gives me the same error